# How to disable z-operations in Spring Redis Template

Tags: java, redis, spring-data, jedis

In Short : How can I disable the use of redis Z-commands in spring.data.redis version 1.7.1.RELEASE?

We were running an early version of springframework.data.redis.RedisCache
That version uses redis z-operations to maintain an index of key names for use in gang operations such as cache.clear() etc.

We have found that these Z operations are massively costly, so we re-wrote RedisCache (it was originally all marked as protected! :( ) to exclude all z-operations.
This works well.. but I notice that the project has come a long way, surely there is a method by which these expensive operations can be prevented using config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short

You can't do it the easy way.

### Explanation

The only ways disabling sorted set commands would be either renaming the commands on Redis or providing an own `RedisTemplate` implementation.

`RedisCache` uses sorted sets to isolate cached data and implement expiry on cache-entry level. In case you're using Spring Boot, it's sufficient to provide an own `CacheManager` bean, so the caching autoconfiguration does not kick in.

We always appreciate feedback on how to improve. Feel free to create a ticket in [our Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS) if you want to contribute or discuss improvements.

Btw, Spring Data Redis 1.7 is the most recent version

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
I realise that there is some conflict between the template and underlying redis implementations. Given that the template is generic and intended to work equally with ehcache, memcached etc.
Redis doesn't really have an underlying concept of 'cache', instead it's all done by keyname. So in order to make redis have a concept of 'cache' (to implement the spring template interface) these sorted sets are used.
Though it seems that it's actually unecessary... I'll try and submit a ticket when I get the chance